# Creating a File that Imports & Immediately Exports Components Again

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

Not sure why this isn't working. I used to have

```
// file 1
import Box from '@/components/Box'
import Popup from '@/components/Popup'

const MDXComponents = {
  Box,
  Popup
}

// using MDXComponents somewhere in file 1
```

Now I want to outsource the MDXComponents object, as it is getting too big. So I created a new file:

```
// file 2
import Box from '@/components/Box'
import Popup from '@/components/Popup'

export default {
  Box,
  Popup
}
```

And then back in file 1 I do:

```
// file 1
import * as MDXComponents from './file2'

// using MDXComponents somewhere in file 1
```

It doesn't let me do this, but I am not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
export default {
  Box,
  Popup
};
```

You **set the default export** to a new object that has 2 properties. You'd need to import like so:

```
import MDXComponents from './file2';
// And then destructure the object like any normal object.
// You can't do import {} in this case, you get the full object.
const { Box } = MDXComponents;
```

When you do this:

```
export {
  Box,
  Popup
};
```

You create **two named exports** that you can import like so:

```
// import all named exports
import * as MDXComponents from './file2';
// or just one individually
import { Box } from './file2';
```

For this use-case [there's also a shortcut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating):

```
export { default as Box } from '@/components/Box';
export { default as Popup } from '@/components/Popup';

// If a module has named exports (not just a default export) 
// and you want to export them all:
export * from 'some-module';

// Or just some:
export { someOtherThing } from '@/components/Box';
export { default as Popup, someOtherThing } from '@/components/Popup';
```